# Xamarin Forms IOS 13 UIUserInterfaceStyle -Dark Mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios13, ios-darkmode

How can I make my app responsive with this "NEW FEATURE" . I want to have an only light mode for now. 
I saw this

```
UIUserInterfaceStyle style = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light;
```

How to activate this on my Xamarin Forms app

Answer (score 2):

You can react to changes in the user interface style by creating two resources: LightTheme and DarkTheme (they will be ResourceDictionaries). Inside them, you can add custom colors. For example:

LightTheme.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="DarkMode.Styles.LightTheme">

    <Color x:Key="background">#FFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="mainLabel">#000000</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

DarkTheme.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="DarkMode.Styles.DarkTheme">

    <Color x:Key="background">#000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="mainLabel">#FFFFFF</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, you have to create a CustomRenderer for the ContentPage element (of course, only for iOS):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof([YOUR_NAMESPACE].iOS.Renderers.PageRenderer))]
namespace [YOUR_NAMESPACE].iOS.Renderers
{
  public class PageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);

      if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
          return;

      try
      {
          SetTheme();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {

      }
    }

    public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
    {
        base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

        if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle)
            SetTheme();
    }

    private void SetTheme()
    {
        if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark)
            App.Current.Resources = new DarkTheme();
        else
            App.Current.Resources = new LightTheme();
    }
  }
}
```

[More information](https://lalorosas.com/blog/dark-mode).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is nessasary. Some pages appears to change the background/text color automatically. I can't figure out why some of pages do it automatically, when others are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can react to mode changes by following the previous comment. If you want to set the mode inside your app, you can do so by setting `Window.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle` in your `AppDelegate.cs` for instance,

`Window.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;`

Here is the full blog post on how to support dark mode in Xamarin.Forms,
https://intelliabb.com/2019/11/02/how-to-support-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/